# 2D Markov Process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, homework

I have a homework project. I need to analyse a gambler's ruin where there are 6 possible outcomes of every wager with corresponding probabilities and payoffs and the gambler may vary the wager (say only 4 values). Am I correct in thinking the gambler's wealth (say 0 to 200 starting at 100) is a 2D random walk with unequal steps. The state space having bankroll on one axis and wager value on the other with bankroll increment determined by outcome, payoff and wager. I can easily simulate this in Excel (or Mathematica) but that won't provide the necessary ruin insight. I could do repeated simulations in Excel stopping at ruin and then derive an empirical PDF of ruin. Mathematica seems to have only 1D RW with equal steps

Comment: I was looking for a built in function, something analogous to DiscreteMarkovProcess, where I can then interrogate the function regarding stopping, ruin etc. Actually generating a walk (as in a single simulation realisation) is trivial, I can write a macro in excel in 5 minutes. But I am a newbie to Mma  and the documentation is very dense in places.

Comment: Also your example looks like it has unit steps

Comment: And equal probabilities. I need to use 6 different probabilities and the payoffs are not all even money, hence the wealth increments are unequal.

Comment: For fixed wagers the problem is also trivial as I can construct a transition matrix to feed into DiscreteMarkovProcess with absorbing states (probability 1) at 0 and 200 corresponding to ruin and doubling wealth respectively. I can then interrogate the function to get ruin/doubling probabilities and other stuff. How do I accomplish the same thing with varying wagers.

Comment: How is the wage going to vary along the process?

Comment: Please remember to start your answers to comments with @username, otherwise the other user doesn't get notified. (as in @belisarius)

Comment: @belisarius Lets say wagers can be 1, 2, 3, 4 and the gambler decides on the value depending on outcome of previous wager. This sounds very like a Markov Decision Process, however if the wagers are algorithmic (say increases wager by 1 (max 4) if previous wager successful otherwise returns to 1). It is not a MDP because I don't want to find a solution to the optimum wager strategy (there likely isn't one). I simply want to specify a wager strategy then compare the ruin/doubling chances with another arbitrary wager strategy.

Comment: @belisarius For fixed wagers it is simple to specify a sparse transition matrix with appropriate absorbing states.

Comment: @belisarius Excellent. The stop condition is the key as this allows me to simulate with absorbing states. Given that there are probably no closed form solutions to most strategies (but say a simple symmetric 1D RW has a closed form solution that can be derived in half a page) I have no choice but to simulate repeatedly and develop empirical results.

Comment: I really don't know if there are theoretic tools to find a closed form. You may ask here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a boilerplate for coding the simulation. I've filled each function with a "reasonable random" behavior for a betting game that follows your experiment description. You should customize them to fit better your simulation needs.

I can't infer from your question what are the random vars for your PDF, but the outcome from the function lets you get (I think) any statistic you may want:

```
allowedWagers[] := {1, 2, 3, 4};
wagerAmount[currentBankRoll_, lastResult_] := Module[{r},
                 While[(r = RandomChoice[allowedWagers[]]) > currentBankRoll]; r]

stopCondition[initialBankRoll_, currentBankRoll_] := Module[{},
  Which[
   currentBankRoll < Min@allowedWagers[], 0, (* 0 == Ruin *)
   currentBankRoll == 2 initialBankRoll,  1, (* 1 == Won *)
   True, 2                                   (* 2 == Continue *)
   ]
  ]

diceF[] := Module[{}, RandomChoice@Range@6]

payOff[dice_] := Module[{payoffs = {-1, -.5, -.2, .2, .4, 1}},(*returns the % gain/loss*)
                         payoffs[[dice]]
  ]

doWalk[initialBankRoll_] := Module[{lastResult = 1, bankRoll = initialBankRoll,
                                    walk = {}, wa, sc, lr},
  While[
   (sc = stopCondition[initialBankRoll, bankRoll]) == 2,
   (bankRoll = bankRoll + (wa=wagerAmount[bankRoll, lastResult]) payOff[lr = diceF[]];
    lastResult = lr;
    AppendTo[walk, {bankRoll, wa}])];
  Return@Append[walk, {sc}]
  ]
```

The "states space" random walk you mentioned in the question:

```
initialBankRoll = 20;
SeedRandom[42];
ListLinePlot[Most@doWalk[initialBankRoll], PlotRangePadding -> {2, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same, viewed as a time-evolution process:

```
initialBankRoll = 20;
SeedRandom[42]; 
Graphics3D[Line@(Prepend@@@ (Transpose@{#,Range@Length@#} &@Most@doWalk[initialBankRoll])), 
           BoxRatios -> {10, 5, 3}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The evolution of the bank roll:

```
initialBankRoll = 20;
SeedRandom[42];
ListLinePlot[Most[doWalk[initialBankRoll][[All, 1]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]